# Minimizing the area of triangle based on three circumcenters

Tags: geometry, optimization, triangles, circles

I'd like to "resurrect" this
[not long time ago deleted question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3726705/122782).
It looks interesting and not immediately obvious
(unless I'm missing something trivial).

[image]

> Given an acute triangle $ABC$  and its circumscribed circle centered
> at $O$. A variable point $X$ is placed  on the minor arc $AB$ of the
> circle; segments $CX$ and $AB$ meet at $D$.  The circumcenters of
> $\triangle ADX$  and $\triangle BDX$ are $Y$ and $Z$, respectively.
> How can we find the  location of the point $X$  for which the area of
> $\triangle OYZ$ is minimized?

Numerical tests suggest that $\triangle OYZ$
is always similar to the reference $\triangle ABC$,
$\angle ZOY=\angle BCA$, and

\begin{align} 
\min_{X\in AB}S_{OYZ}(X)
&=\tfrac14\,S_{ABC}
\end{align}

when $CX\perp AB$.

Complex numbers/coordinate geometry approach
with unit circle centered at the origin
using known function for
line/line intersection
and the location of the circumcenter
based on the coordinates of the three vertices
lead to too unreasonably overcomplicated expressions.

Comment: I don't have the time to fully calculate this, but you can WLOG define triangle ABC so that the points are on the unit circle, line AB is parallel to the x axis, and line AB has a negative y coordinate.  We can then define points D, Y, and Z as a function on the x coordinate of A, the x coordinate of C, and the x coordinate of X.  Then, using Gauss's shoelace formula, we can find the area of triangle OYZ as a function of these three variables.  Then, optimize the area by taking the partial derivative with respect to the x coordinate of X and solving to find minima and maxima

Comment: @Moko: that's exactly what I tried to do, but 
as I mentioned, expressions become too complex.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Using standard notation for the angles of $\triangle ABC$.
inscribed into the unit circle,
$\angle XOA=\theta\in(0,2\gamma)$,
coordinates of the points are

\begin{align}
O&=(0,0)
,\quad
A=(-\sin\gamma,\,-\cos\gamma)
,\quad
B=(\phantom{-}\sin\gamma,\,-\cos\gamma)
\tag{1}\label{1}
,\\
C&=(\sin(2\alpha+\gamma),\,-\cos(2\alpha+\gamma))
,\quad
X=(\sin(\theta-\gamma),\, -\cos(\theta-\gamma))
\tag{2}\label{2}
,\\
D&=\left(
\frac{
2\sin(\alpha+\gamma)\sin\tfrac12\theta
-\sin\gamma\sin(\alpha+\tfrac12\theta)
}{\sin(\alpha+\tfrac12\theta)}
,\,
-\cos\gamma
\right)
\tag{3}\label{3}
.
\end{align}

Corresponding coordinates of the points $Y$ and $Z$ can be found as

\begin{align}
Y&=\left(
-\sin\gamma
+\frac{\sin(\alpha+\gamma)\sin\tfrac12\theta}{\sin(\alpha+\tfrac12\theta)}
,\,
\phantom{-}\frac{\sin\alpha\sin(\theta-2\gamma)}
{2\,\sin(\alpha+\tfrac12\theta)\sin(\gamma-\tfrac12\theta)}
\right)
\tag{4}\label{4}
,\\
Z&=\left(
\phantom{-}\sin\gamma
+\frac{\sin\alpha\sin(\tfrac12\,\theta-\gamma)}{\sin(\alpha+\tfrac12\,\theta)}
,\,
-\frac{\sin(\alpha+\gamma)\sin\theta}{2\,\sin(\alpha+\tfrac12\,\theta)\sin\tfrac12\,\theta}
\right)
\tag{5}\label{5}
.
\end{align}

Given the coordinates of $O,Y,Z$, the squared area of $\triangle OYZ$
in terms of $\theta$
can be found as

\begin{align}
S_{OYZ}^2(\theta)=
&\left( 
    \sin\tfrac12\theta\sin(\gamma-\tfrac12\theta)
    \, (
      \sin^2\alpha\, \sin(2\, \gamma-\theta)+\sin^2\beta\, \sin\theta
     )
\right.
\\     
&\left.   -\sin\gamma\, \sin(\alpha+\tfrac12\theta)
   \, ( \sin\alpha\, \sin(\tfrac12\theta)\, \sin(2\, \gamma-\theta)
     +\sin\beta\, \sin\theta\, \sin(\gamma-\tfrac12\theta)
    )
\right)^2
\\
&\left/(4\, \sin\tfrac12\theta\, \sin(\gamma-\tfrac12\theta)\, \sin^2(\alpha+\tfrac12\theta))^{2}
\right.
\tag{6}\label{6}
.
\end{align}

Expression for $\frac d{d\theta}(S_{OYZ}^2(\theta))$
is rather complicated,
but it indeed reaches zero at $\theta=\pi-2\alpha$,
when $CX\perp AB$.

Answer (score 0):

1. How do we find $Y$ and $Z$? $Y$ lies on perpendicular bisectors
   of $AX$ and $DX$, $Z$ lies on perpendicular bisectors of $XB$ and $DX$.
   Note, that $O$ lies on perpendicular bisectors of $AX$ and $XB$.

[image: figure for perpendicular bisectors]

2. Perform homothety centred at $X$ with coefficient $2$.
   Midpoints of $AX$, $DX$ and $XB$ go to points $A$, $D$, $B$ respectively.
   Perpendicular bisectors go to perpendicular lines, passing through these
   points, and $O$ goes to diametrically opposite to $X$, say $X'$.

[image: figure for homothety and the solution]

3. $\angle X'CX=90^\circ$ $\Rightarrow$ $CX'\perp CD$ and $Y'Z'\perp CD$
   $\Rightarrow$ $CX'||Y'Z'$
4. Though there are some cases of points positioning, but I'm feeling lazy
   to deal with it. Sometimes an angle is simply that angle but sometimes
   $180^\circ-$angle.
   $\angle A=180^\circ-\angle CX'B=\angle X'Z'Y'$
   $\angle B=\angle CX'A=\angle X'Y'Z'$
   $\Rightarrow$ $\triangle X'Z'Y'\sim \triangle CAB$
5. $CX'||Y'Z'$ $\Rightarrow$ length of $CD$ is the length of height
   from $X'$ in the $\triangle Y'X'Z'$.
   In the $\triangle ACB$ length of the corresponding height is not more
   than $CD$ (and equal when $CD$ is the height), i.e. the similarity coefficient
   $\displaystyle\frac{CD}{h}\ge 1$ and $S_{X'Y'Z'}=4S_{OYZ}$.

Comment: Downvoters please care to explain why. Thanks.

Comment: @Alexey Burdin: agree. My wild guess - perhaps, some oversized images?
Just in case, I crop them a little.

Comment: I have access to the exact geogebra sources -- [here](https://www.geogebra.org/m/frmv7udw) and [here](https://www.geogebra.org/m/pdeuggpx) -- in case you have an idea how can the images be made better. _Now_ they appears oversized)) I'd leave `height="250"` alone))) Thanks. Is solution clear?